# Can you help me with, how the incrementing works here in 6th and 7th print statement

Tags: c

As you can see the output of the 6th and 7th print statement shows some random integer value, and I don't know why its happening!!!

```
    6--> 4      5      4204752
    7--> 4      5      4204753
```

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    static int a[]  = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    static int* p[] = {a, a + 1, a + 2, a + 3, a + 4};

    int** ptr;
    ptr = p;
    ptr++;
    printf("1-->%d      %d      %d\n", ptr - p, *ptr - a, **ptr);

    *ptr++;
    printf("2-->%d      %d      %d\n", ptr - p, *ptr - a, **ptr);

    *++ptr;
    printf("3-->%d      %d      %d\n", ptr - p, *ptr - a, **ptr);

    ++*ptr;
    printf("4-->%d      %d      %d\n", ptr - p, *ptr - a, **ptr);

    **ptr++;
    printf("5-->%d      %d      %d\n", ptr - p, *ptr - a, **ptr);

    *++*ptr;
    printf("6-->%d      %d      %d\n", ptr - p, *ptr - a, **ptr);

    ++**ptr;
    printf("7-->%d      %d      %d\n", ptr - p, *ptr - a, **ptr);
}
```

Comment: How many elements are there in the p array and a array? Which ones are lines 6 and 7 reading?

Comment: "I'm getting some random integer value" is usually that you're reading an uninitialized variable, or accessing an array out of bounds. Here it's presumably accessing an array out of bounds.

Comment: It's not your problem here, but note that `ptr-p` is of type `ptrdiff_t`, but you print it with `%d`. That may or may not work depending on compiler options.

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning `p` points to `p[0]`.

First three increments change `p` to point `p[3]`. Dereferences do nothing.

Fourth increment `++*ptr` increments `p[3]` to `a + 4`.

Fifth increment changes `p` to `p[4]`. Again the dereferences do nothing.

Sixth increment first changes `p[4]` to `a + 5`. This is out of range for `a`, but as a special rule pointing to address past end of array is allowed. But then there is dereference, which tries to read `a[5]` and that results in *undefined behaviour*.

Seventh increment tries to increment `a[5]` by one, but this is again *undefined behaviour*.

So, to answer your question why last 2 print weird values, is because you read and write outside of array bounds. Program is broken and you get garbage results.

Answer (score 1):

Initial condition:

```
  ptr == &p[0]                 // int ** == int **
 *ptr ==  p[0] == &a[0]        // int *  == int *  == int *
**ptr == *p[0] ==  a[0] == 0   // int    == int    == int    == int
```

After `ptr++`:

```
  ptr == &p[1]            
 *ptr ==  p[1]  == &a[1]
**ptr == *p[1]  ==  a[1] == 1
```

After `*ptr++` (parsed as `*(ptr++)`, result of dereferencing `ptr++` is discarded):

```
  ptr == &p[2]
 *ptr ==  p[2]  == &a[2]
**ptr == *p[2]  ==  a[2] == 2
```

After `*++ptr` (parsed as `*(++ptr)`, result of dereferencing `++ptr` is discarded):

```
  ptr == &p[3]
 *ptr ==  p[3]  == &a[3]
**ptr == *p[3]  ==  a[3] == 3
```

After `++*ptr` (parsed as `++(*ptr)`, meaning you're not incrementing `ptr` but the thing `ptr` *points to* (`p[3]`):

```
  ptr == &p[3]
 *ptr ==  p[3]  == &a[4] 
          ^
          |
          +--- operand of ++

**ptr == *p[3]  ==  a[4] == 4
```

After `**ptr++` (which is parsed as `*(*(ptr++))`, results of the dereferences are discarded):

```
  ptr == &p[4]
 *ptr ==  p[4] == &a[4]
**ptr == *p[4] ==  a[4] == 4
```

After `*++*ptr` (which is parsed as `*(++(*ptr))`, so again you're not incrementing `ptr` but the thing `ptr` points to (`p[4]`) - result of the outer dereference is discarded):

```
  ptr == &p[4]
 *ptr ==  p[4] == &a[5] 
          ^
          |
          +--- operand of ++

**ptr == *p[4] ==  a[5] == ???
```

Problem - `p[4]` initially points to `a[4]`, which is the last element of `a`.  Incrementing `p[4]` causes it to point to one element past the end of `a`.

Finally, `++**ptr` (which is parsed as `++(*(*ptr))`, so you're incrementing the thing that whatever `ptr` points to, points to; unfortunately, as shown above, `**ptr` evaluates to something outside the bounds of `a`)

```
  ptr == &p[4]
 *ptr ==  p[4] == &a[5]
**ptr == *p[r] ==  a[5] == ???
                   ^
                   |
                   +--- operand of ++
```

Comment: Thanks mate for the detailed explanation helps a lot....